# Do I need a battery protection IC with LTC4091 charger?

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion, circuit-protection

I am designing a data-logger circuit powered by my car's 12 V switched bus and a 18650 Li-ion single cell as backup power.

I am using an [Analog Devices LTC4091](https://www.analog.com/en/products/ltc4091.html) Li-ion charger IC, with the same circuit as presented in the Datasheet Typical Application:

[image: LTC4091 Typical Application]

I would like to be able to use an unprotected 18650 Li-ion battery.

I understand that the LTC4091 disables the battery charging circuit when :

- undervoltage occurs
- overvoltage occurs (charging stops at 4.1 V or 4.2 V)
- temperature is too low or too high (via an NTC thermistor)

Additionally I<sub>out</sub> is limited via an inductor to ~2.4 A.

Does the above qualifies as a battery protection circuit? Otherwise I am looking at adding a chip such as the [AP9101C](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP9101C.pdf), but I am wondering if this would be redundant with the LTC4091 functions.

Comment: Does the undervoltage lockout mentioned in the datasheet refer to the charger or the battery? Does the IC provide over/undervoltage and current protection for the battery *when the battery is being used to power the load* and there is no charging? Anyway, consider that protection circuits are also there to keep the battery safe when the charger fails.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this design includes a full protection of the Li Ion battery and circuit protection from car transients to 36V.

OVP, UVP, OCP, OTP, UTP are included with a seamless transition to input cutoff/turnon.  Adherence to App note layout details is crucial.

Comment: Would you mind expanding on your answer about the protections ? The datasheet doesn't explicitly mention protections, but only that the charging stops when some conditions are met (high temp, low voltage...). It doesn't seem that battery gets isolated from the circuit at any point as with the AP9101C chip mentioned in my post. But I have trouble understanding the block diagram provided in the datasheet and whether "stops charging" is equivalent to isolating the battery.

Comment: The IC must control battery current separate from the load Out to do this and I cannot verify if load voltage regulates without a battery installed. Ask LTC